# Getting "Already defines a member function" and "already contains a definition" errors when compiling CS website

Tags: c#

I inherited an ASPX website from an ex-employee (I'm a PHP developer) and am having trouble compiling the .csproj file.

I tried removing the duplicate functions and the errors begin to dwindle. However, these obviously are needed since they were in the application to begin with.

See image: [image]

Comment: Looks like you got a bad copy of the code.  Is it in source control?  Check the history of the solution/project to see what changed recently.  Also try getting latest with overwrite.  Maybe something is just jacked up on the local dev box you are using.  A new pull should resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the things I have done in the past when I have had practically everything error for no reason after getting the solution from someone.

- Check the references of every project. It is very common to get a solution/project and not have references found.
- If you have more than one project, build each one, one by one. Try to start with the core projects that don't rely on others and work your way through the chain. Doing this allows you to find the project that is causing issues that others are depending on. I would also suggest doing a Clean and Rebuild so you can eliminate half of the errors that aren't related to that project.
- Try to go through the error list ignoring all of the same errors. There could be another error causing the rest. It's a pain, but not much you can really do.
- If the employee's dev machine is still accessible, have someone with authority change the ex-employee's password and log in as them. You'll be able to confirm the project actually builds on their system and also will be able to compare any differences between your copy and theirs.

Good luck!

Comment: These are good points. I've loaded projects from source control that referenced libraries on drives mapped to the original developers machine that didn't exist on my own. Sheesh.

Comment: @mafafu Yea, it can be a real pain sometimes getting solutions that are quite robust and only a single developer has ever touched it. The *best* is when some files are never actually associated with source control, but is in the developer's code folder.